# How to interpolate a vector field with Python?

Tags: python, numpy, vector, interpolation

I have a 2D vector field (in fact it's a 3D, but if we know how to do it with 2D, I think it will be easy to generalize to 3D) like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np
x = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2]
y = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5]
u = [0.5, -1, 0, 0, 0.25, 1, 0, 0, 0.75]
v = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
plt.quiver(x, y, u, v)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**How to interpolate smoothly this vector field?**

I know how to use `np.polyfit` but I don't see how to do an interpolation for a vector field.

Example: I would like to interpolate `[0,2]x[1,2]` with hundreds of arrows.

Comment: I have a similar problem these days, too, and am using numpy's `RegularGridInterpolator`. Seeing here that numpy only provides linear (or stepwise of course) interpolation makes me doubt, that you can easily expand solutions in dimenionality. However: try this on every vector component you have, it should be a valid first step.

Comment: @SpghttCd Thank you for your comment. If you have sample code, could you post it as an answer (or even partial answer)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, `RegularGridInterpolator` is also from scipy, not from numpy, so it won't be too different from HansHirse's solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using NumPy's [`meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) and SciPy's [`interpolate.griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) methods, this might be a fast and feasible solution:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

x = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2]
y = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5]
u = [0.5, -1, 0, 0, 0.25, 1, 0, 0, 0.75]
v = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

plt.figure(1)
plt.quiver(x, y, u, v)

xx = np.linspace(0, 2, 10)
yy = np.linspace(1, 2, 10)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)

points = np.transpose(np.vstack((x, y)))
u_interp = interpolate.griddata(points, u, (xx, yy), method='cubic')
v_interp = interpolate.griddata(points, v, (xx, yy), method='cubic')

plt.figure(2)
plt.quiver(xx, yy, u_interp, v_interp)
plt.show()
```

Output of the interpolated plot:

[image: Output]

Playing around with the number of points to be created within the `np.linspace` calls, gives you more or less arrows.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, it's perfect!

Comment: PS: I tried with 3D data, and I get `ValueError: Unknown interpolation method 'cubic' for 3 dimensional data`. Any idea for a quick fix, or does this require a totally different method?

Comment: @Basj In the documentation on `interpolate.griddata`, it's mentioned that `cubic` is just available for 1-D and 2-D data. Try `linear` instead.

Comment: Thank you. Note: `fill_value=0` might be needed to avoid `nan` values.

Comment: Last last thing @HansHirse: how could we evaluate the model / interpolate for specific values of x,y? Example: Which interpolated vector for `x=1.121, y=1.342`? Of course I could use a meshgrid with step 0.001 and find the right point in this meshgrid, but this would be inefficient for large meshgrids. Is there a way to get the output of the model for a given x,y?

Comment: @Basj Just call `interpolate.griddata` again just for these specific coordinates. If you don't have masses of them thus calling the method too often, I think that should be OK here.